# Laravel Artisan Hangs using Memory Until Freeze

Tags: php, laravel, php-7, laravel-artisan, laravel-5.4

With Laravel 5.4 Artisan will not run and uses a lot of memory, it worked a long while before with the same versions (besides PHP 7.0.14 to 7.0.15 maybe?).

**Problem**: any `$ ./artistan` command does nothing. While watching `htop` I notice the memory climb from `2gb` to `4gb` very quickly. Once I cancel it, it jumps back down.

**What Im Using**

- Ubuntu Linux Xenial x64 (Local Development)
- Apache2.4
- MySQL 5.7
- PHP 7.0.15

  - Laravel 5.4
  - Composer 1.3.2

**PHP Extensions Loaded**

```
[PHP Modules]
bz2
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
fileinfo
filter
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
igbinary
imap
intl
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
odbc
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
PDO_ODBC
Phar
posix
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
wddx
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

**Things I've Tried:**

- Removed the bootstrap/cache/config.php file.

  - `composer dumpautoload`
  - `composer self-update`
- The Artisan commands don't work below

  - `php artisan clear-compiled`
  - `php artisan optimize`
  - `php artisan optimize --force`

**My Guess**
I'm guessing I have a PHP extension enabled causing the problem but I wouldn't know which -- Please let me know if you have any ideas or clues.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to leave it running until it runs out of memory to see the error message?

Comment: Yeah, It ends up going up to 8GB memory (maxing out) and the computer can barely move or do anything so I have to shut down.

Comment: Change your php.ini to not allow more than 500MB of RAM for PHP and then run `php artisan`. Your computer will still survive and once artisan reaches 500MB, PHP will throw an error with a backtrace. Make sure to have XDEBUG, of course.

Comment: the limit prevents a crash thanks! I have: 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/jesse/projects/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 549

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 524288000 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /home/jesse/projects/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 549

Comment: I compild xdebug and enabled it, looks like it repeats this forever 0.0190    3213016  93. Illuminate\Log\LogServiceProvider->configureHandler() /home/jesse/projects/platform/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Log/LogServiceProvider.php:60

Comment: Sounds like your ServiceProvider is trying to register a Service Provider and they're in a loop trying register each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's missing ::class I had the same problem, just like you, one little mistake.

Comment: Wow! Thank you, I can't believe it!

Comment: i didnt understand the solution. I am also facing the same problem. Where to add ::class

Comment: @SanthoshYedidi: They are talking about JREAMs answer from Mar 5, 5:55. In the code snippet he provides, you have to append `::class`, like this:

`$providers => [ ... Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider::class ...]`

Comment: That was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Did a new installation, and this is causing it:

**config.php/app**

```
$providers => [
...
Laravel\Cashier\CashierServiceProvider
...
]
```

from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/billing

I'm not sure why this is causing it. I have followed the instructions with no implementation (I cannot migrate without artisan running either. This is odd but fixes it for now.