# Laravel php artisan migrate does nothing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-valet

am quite new to php laravel. Been watching laracasts to try to get valey working but hitting a wall at "php artisan migrate".

I've tried running a few commands like below but nothing works. The problem is after typing "php artisan migrate" in the folder where laravel is installed, it just does literally nothing. No error messages whatsoever. I've tried letting it run for a few hours but it just stays the same, remains at command without running anything.

```
>PB-no-MacBook-Pro:blog pb$ php artisan migrate --verbose
>^Z
>[1]+  Stopped                 php artisan migrate --verbose
>PB-no-MacBook-Pro:blog pb$ php artisan migrate:rollback
>^Z
>[2]+  Stopped                 php artisan migrate:rollback
>PB-no-MacBook-Pro:blog pb$ php artisan migrate
```

Been cracking my head around this one for a good week or two now. Been searching online for solutions but have not been able to find a solution for the situation I'm facing so far. Really hope someone can help.

Thank you.

Comment: Is your database on your local machine or a remote server?

Comment: @Mike shouldn't make a different to whether the command actually runs or not. If there is an error with the DB it would come back as so.

Comment: If you type `valet` in the terminal, does it come back with all the valet commands? In otherwords, is it installed?

Comment: According to the answers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599247/laravel-artisan-hangs-using-memory-until-freeze) you might be missing a `::class` in one of the `providers` or `aliases` in `config/app.php`. Check that.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response guys!
database is on local machine.
valet returns commands.
Will try to check out the ::class issue again. Saw that thread earlier but doubt it solved my problem.
Database seems to be acting strange. I've tried connecting to localhost and 127.0.0.1 via Sequel Pro but it's returning an error in connection. However in the command prompt, it shows mysql is already started and running. Will continue to investigate further.

Comment: Just double checked ::class, it's all there, nothing seems to be missing.

Comment: Some quick updates.
Good news: Managed to connect to mysql, seems to be a problem with the new version. Solution here:
https://www.farces.com/wrestling-with-the-mysql-8-0-11-bear/

Not so good news: 
php artisan migrate still does nothing. :/