# Laravel update from 5.1.46 to 5.2.* php artisan Segmentation fault

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I'm working to update a Laravel project from 5.1.46 to 5.2.*. After I followed the steps from here https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0 I have ran the command

```
./composer.phar update
```

I receive the follow error when the composer tries to run

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

I tried to run manually the command

```
php artisan clear-compiled -vvv
```

But I have exactly the same output. Do you have any idea how can I debug what is causes this?
This appears with PHP 5.6.
Also I've tried to use PHP 7.4, but it looks like the computer runs out of memory. For some reason the artisan is taking the entire memory of the computer, until the computer freezes.

Thanks!

**Later Edit:**

I have used PHP 7.2 with memory limit up to 8G, and I have the following output:

```
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 8589934592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in /d/projects/a-car/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 616
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 8589934592 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in Unknown on line 0
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

Comment: are you on windows? is your php a 32-bit or 64-bit one? 32-bit version might only able to use less memory (only 2GB if i'm not wrong). see [this QA regarding that magic number 262144](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39115378/4648586) it may help.

Comment: Do any artisan commands run? If not, it might be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42599247/laravel-artisan-hangs-using-memory-until-freeze)

Comment: Have you tried deleting vendor directory and running `composer install`?

Comment: it looks like the issue was with a library that was loaded but it wasn't compatible with Laravel 5.2. I have solved by removing the library for the moment and I'm working on update for that library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the issue was with a library that was loaded but it wasn't compatible with Laravel 5.2. I have solved by removing the library for the moment and I'm working on update for that library (SleepingOwl).